# Shadow inside of a div

Tags: css, shadow

Is it possible to display a shadow inside a div box without using pictures?
Instead I want to use css commands.

So is there some command like: `-webkit-box-shadow: 1px inset;` ?

Comment: They actually use image in the tumblr website, two images to be precise. One shadow image for full page width and second broader shadow image in the center of the page.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In CSS3 there's [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-shadow) which can also be inset to do exactly what you need. This is supported by the following browsers:

- Chrome >= 10.0 (>= 4.0 with `-webkit` prefix)
- Firefox >= 4.0 (>= 3.5 with `-moz` prefix)
- IE >= 9.0
- Opera >= 10.5
- Safari >= 5.1 (>= 5.0 with `-webkit` prefix)

Comment: -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2em 3em -1em green;
solved it. Thanks :)

Comment: you're welcome. please keep in mind to accept the answer that solved your problem by clicking on the tick-mark to the left of it.

Answer (score 39):

Yup there is a command `inset`. like this:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px #000 inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px #000 inset;
box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px #000 inset;
```

You can generate from here http://css3generator.com/

Comment: StackOverflow code highlighting seems to think `inset` is part of a comment `#000 inset` **.....**

Answer (score 0):

You can use Box [shadow generator](http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow) for shadow effects.  I will give an example to show how to use the box shadow generator.

Step 1: Go to : [Box Shadow Generator](http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow)

Step 2: adjust the shadow property you want to add.

Step 3: Then copy the css code using "copy text" button.

step 4: Then you can past the css code into the style sheet file.

Do like this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #banner{

        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: #4E6C88;
        -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 9px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: -1px 9px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        box-shadow: -1px 9px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="banner">    

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you... ;)